# EditText validation message box Xamarin c# android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, input, xamarin.android

Does anyone know how to make a message box when a value is entered in the EditText.Text ?? 
Example:  User(x) clicks form and puts in a value... if the value is 10 or higher he/she gets an error message and the value is set to default value of 0... Ive was getting an error at first saying something down the lines of ' Input string is not formatted correctly' when i would try and convert.ToInt32 or Int.Parse... but I placed EditText.Text = "10"; and it seemed to work but when i put the loop in it crashes and doesnt show me the error.

```
EditText.Text = "10";
int x = Convert.ToInt32(EditText.Text.ToString()) // or Int.Parse(EditText.Text.Tostring())

// Validation
if( x >= 10) 
{
//message box appears and says you cant have a number 10 or higher then sets the value of x to 0
}
// Else sets x to the value the user puts in the editText.Text
```

Ive tried multiple ways,
Thanks.

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 1):

You could to listen to the EditText `TextChanged` event,and set the EditText `selection` to the end, use `Toast` or `Dialog` to show the error message  :

```
EditText edit = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit);
edit.TextChanged += Edit_TextChanged;

private void Edit_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.Parse(e.Text.ToString())>10)
        {
            edit.Text = "0";
            edit.SetSelection(edit.Text.Length);
            Toast.MakeText(this, "you cant have a number 10 or higher", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works temporarily if i type in a number 11 the message will appear and it will be set to 0... But when i try to put in a new value like 5 it throws an exception (int.Parse(e.Text.ToString())>10)      System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: you should judge if e.Text.ToString() is null first